# Windows Batch file; find specific file type and copy to a folder keeping the relative folder structure

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a windows batch file that can recursively find all *.txt files and copy to a  target directory, but persisting the relative directory structures.

For example

```
/examples
    /a
        /data
            a.txt
            b.txt
        /source
            a.js
            b.js
    /b
       /data
            c.txt
            d.txt
       /images
            a.png
```

Copy to testCopy folder

```
/textCopy
    /a
        /data
            a.txt
            b.txt

    /b
       /data
            c.txt
            d.txt
```

My current environment for windows is XP and I won't be able to use Robocopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xcopy /s examples\*.txt textCopy\
```

Comment: how would you know if the folder contains *.txt files.

Comment: @user1721547 - The /S option will not create an empty folder. Read the documentation available by typing `HELP XCOPY` from the command line.